# Problems with GestureListener

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, gestures

I have a class declared as this:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
```

The interface im implementing is `import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;`

As class var i have a GestureDetector (`private GestureDetector gestureDetector;`) which i init on the onCreate event: `gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);`

And after this, i override the interface methods:

```
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.w(this.getClass().toString(), e.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.w(this.getClass().toString(),e.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.w(this.getClass().toString(),e.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    Log.w(this.getClass().toString(),e1.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.w(this.getClass().toString(),e.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.w(this.getClass().toString(),e1.toString());
    return true;
}
```

I found an example doing this with a deprecated constructor for the GestureListener (`new GestureDetector(this)`) but i cant do it work either.

What step am i forgetting?

Comment: Have you done something like this to your views in the Activity?  tView.SetOnTouchListener(m_gestureListener);

Comment: @pskink i think so, but its not writing any log or stop on debug points

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds no, just init the GestureDetector. As the class implements it i suppose its implicit

Comment: how do you feed your GestureDetector?

Comment: @pskink with constructor

Comment: no, where do you call GestureDetector#onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)?

Comment: @pskink on the example i saw there was no direct call

Comment: you have to feed it somehow with MotionEvents, otherwise you will see nothing

Comment: @pskink, basicly the Laurent's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GestureDetector as this:

```
// Gesture detection
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
viewFlipperProduct.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.performClick();
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});

private class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it was this. As @pskink told before i had to feed it. Thank you